# Flutter shows random error on iOS simulator, or build fails on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I was building up a flutter project, and it shows random issues from yesterday.

Error:

> Exception: Unable to get Xcode project information:
> 2022-05-21 11:24:21.526 xcodebuild[59059:315927] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
> 2022-05-21 11:24:21.527 xcodebuild[59059:315927] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

How can I resolve this issue?
My project got completely stuck on this and had implemented some random solutions like removing and installing CommandLineTools, etc. But no changes. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

flutter doctor -v output :

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable,
> 3.0.1, on macOS 12.4 21F79
> darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
> • Flutter version 3.0.1 at
> /Users/carclenx/developme
> nt/flutter
> • Upstream repository
> https://github.com/flutte
> r/flutter.git
> • Framework revision
> fb57da5f94 (32 hours
> ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29
> -0700
> • Engine revision
> caaafc5604
> • Dart version 2.17.1
> • DevTools version 2.12.2

> [✓] Android toolchain - develop
> for Android devices
> (Android SDK version
> 32.0.0)
> • Android SDK at
> /Users/carclenx/Library/A
> ndroid/sdk
> • Platform android-32,
> build-tools 32.0.0
> • Java binary at:
> /Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents/jre/C
> ontents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK
> Runtime Environment
> (build
> 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
> • All Android licenses
> accepted.

> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and
> macOS (Xcode 13.4)
> • Xcode at
> /Applications/Xcode.app/C
> ontents/Developer
> • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

> [✓] Chrome - develop for the
> web
> • Chrome at
> /Applications/Google
> Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS
> /Google Chrome

> [✓] Android Studio (version
> 2021.1)
> • Android Studio at
> /Applications/Android
> Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be
> installed from:
>
> https://plugins.jetbrains
> .com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be
> installed from:
>
> https://plugins.jetbrains
> .com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK
> Runtime Environment
> (build
> 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

> [✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
> • VS Code at
> /Applications/VS
> Code.app/Contents
> • Flutter extension version
> 3.41.20220516

> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> • iPhone 13 Pro Max (mobile) •
> D4210C1C-C70E-48EF-8DD4-0A66830A19EF • ios
> • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-5
> (simulator)
> • macOS (desktop)            • macos
> • darwin-arm64   • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm
> • Chrome (web)               • chrome
> • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.64

> [✓] HTTP Host Availability
> • All required HTTP hosts are available

> • No issues found!

Comment: your xcode is updated?

Comment: Yes. As per AppStore, I have the 13.4 version. @AliPunjabi

Comment: And also, my other projects don't have this kind of issue.

Comment: downgrade xcode and check

Comment: also attach flutter doctor -v report in your question

Comment: which version do you prefer? @AliPunjabi

Comment: I am using 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too. Tried updating everything(MacOS, Flutter version,[already using latest XCode]) to the latest version but did not work. But after adding "-lc++" to Other Linker Flags in my Build Settings, did the trick for me.

[image]